# How do I download AND save mp3 music files to Rhythmbox?

Tags: sound, music, rhythmbox, mp3

First of all, I'm sorry, I really have no idea what I'm doing, so please be patient with me. I'm having troubles with Rhythmbox. I would like to download some mp3 music files from a site (yes, I do have permission) and be able to have them saved onto Rhythmbox so I can play them whenever I want to. I was able to download the files onto my computer, open them up with the archive manager, and play them with Rhythmbox, but then whenever I exited out of the archive manager, they were instantly gone from Rhythmbox. The extra weird part is that with the SAME site, I've managed to do what I want (twice) with some other music files, but it took forever and I honestly have no idea how I did it, it just worked at some point. Please help!

Comment: I don't have rhythembox installed so I can't do an exact answer but you need to go to `file` in rhythembox and look for `import media` or some thing very close, then you can point it to the folder the music is located in.

Comment: I tried that, but the folder with the music wouldn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the mp3's in some folder and open them from there.

When you open a file from the Archive Manager, the file is saved in a temporary hidden .cache folder located in /home/user and it gets open from there. 
You can play the file with Rhythmbox but you can't import it. In order to import it, you need to save the mp3 in a folder like /home/user/music.

Comment: Well either way, it worked, so I'm good, thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: @AMurry If this is the answer that worked, please click the checkmark on the left to thank the user and let others find the right answer.

Comment: @user2765257 I guess you were trying to answer the question, can you improve your answer at all? It really lacks content and won't likely survive review, if you can add some more detail, I will change my vote from -1 to +1.

Comment: Looks better now ;)

Comment: I changed my vote. REVIEWERS: I was wrong to flag this, it was correct and the user made an effort to edit, so please don't downvote and close. My bad.

Comment: I also voted on some of your questions to make up for the other downvote I got you, sorry :)